# Errors for Temp table

Tags: java

Im just a beginner any help would be very much apreciated. thanks for your time.

Jgrasp gives me these errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException:
>   d != java.lang.Doubleat
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)
>   at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2709)
>   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2661) at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2433) at
>   java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920) at
>   java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821) at
>   TempTable.main(TempTable.java:25) –

**my code**

```
public class TempTable
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      double cdeg;
      double fdeg;

        System.out.println("Fahrenheit"+"\t"+"Celsius");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

      for ( cdeg = 0;  cdeg <= 20;  cdeg++) 
        {
                fdeg = 1.8 * cdeg + 32;

            System.out.printf( "    %3d C = %5.1f F\n", cdeg, fdeg );
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as the stack trace tells you:

> `d != java.lang.Double`

and

> `printInteger(Formatter.java:2709)`

You're using the `d` format specifier, but you're trying to format a `double`. So either cast the double to an int:

```
System.out.printf( "    %3d C = %5.1f F\n", (int) cdeg, fdeg );
```

or use a floating-point format specifier:

```
System.out.printf( "    %3f C = %5.1f F\n", cdeg, fdeg );
```

or, **most strongly recommended,** use an `int`, not a `double`, for your loop counter.

Comment: Thanks man with this it helped me solve a bunch of other problems!